# How to know max RAM memory allowed?

Tags: linux, memory, ram, lubuntu

I found an old HP 530 laptop and am planning to upgrade it with an SSD and new RAM to give it to my little brother for his schools tasks.

I executed the dmidecode command to know the sistem specs and I got the following output:

```
Handle 0x000A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000A
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM #1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 975 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 7F7FFE0000000000
    Serial Number: 5CB5368D
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: EBE10UE8AFSA-8G-F 

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000A
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM #2
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
    Serial Number: F405601E
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M4 70T2953CZ3-CE6 

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000A
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000B
    Memory Array Ma    Handle 0x000A, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000A
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM #1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 975 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 7F7FFE0000000000
    Serial Number: 5CB5368D
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: EBE10UE8AFSA-8G-F 

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000A
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM #2
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MT/s
    Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
    Serial Number: F405601E
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: M4 70T2953CZ3-CE6 

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 2 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x000A
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000B
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00040000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000C
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 2pped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00040000000
    Ending Address: 0x0007FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x000C
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x000D
    Partition Row Position: 2
```

As I can understand, the max ammount of Ram memory is 4GB, but Im not sure if should I buy a single 4gb stick or two 2GB sticks. Which type of memory (DDR2?) should I buy?

Anyone can help me?

Thank you all :)

Comment: [This any use to you?](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/HP-530-NOTEBOOK-RAM-UPGRADE/td-p/5831743)

Comment: @bu5hman, I have read all threads on HP forum but there are mixed answers: some say that the max capacity is 2gb, others say that is 3 gb and someone said that his laptop allowed 4gb.

Comment: Well, 2GB of old DDR isn't going to break the bank... Give it a shot. Though personally I would be surprised if the hardware was THAT variable and most of the posts I read say there are physical slots for 4GB but only 2GB is addressable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HP forums and the manual I've found maximum memory is limited to 2GB.

For more information just read page 1 and 2 of the following Maintenance & Service guide for the HP 530 notebook.

Click on the [link](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01039180) to read the pdf document

Comment: I already read the Maintenance & Service guide for the HP 530, but if you look at the first block of the output that I share in the post, it says that the maximum capacity is 4GB. 

I dont know to trust in the Maintenence Guide or in the output that I get from the Linux terminal.

Comment: Might be the case the info is wrong on the app due to the hardware being old and untested (wild guess) so I would stick with the manual.

Comment: For one of my laptops: The service manual says maximum 3GB; It is currently happily using 8GB. I can't remember how I determined that it could use 8GB. The season for the limit was the 32bit MS-Windows OS, that it is no-longer running.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, that's interesting. I´m going to take the risk and will buy two 2gb RAM modules. I will upgrade this answer when I test it.

Comment: They may say "2GB" because there was no larger sticks available, or no larger HP-approved sticks in the day.  I know lenovo X220 officially supports 8GB only, as the largest suitable sticks were 4 GB back then.  But people have used it with 2x8GB later.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm intrigued by the odd number.  The the laptop have three memory buses or was the manual author just making it up as they went along?

Comment: @PhilipCouling 3GB was the limit with 32bit MS-Windows (See end of my comment). This is because 1GB is used by the kernel (32bit Linux has the same limit, in standard configuration. The limit will always be less that 4GB, no matter the configuration). PAE-Linux has a higher RAM limit, but still 3GB per process.